# How to write json file with duplicate keys in Python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I need help to write my data to json file on below format,

```
{
    "Employees": {
        "Employee": {
            "name": "john"
             ....
        },
        "Employee": {
            "name": "Taylor"
             ....   
        },
        "Employee": {

            "name": "Prab"
             ....
        }
    }
}
```

Here Employee key should be repeated for each node,  since Python dictionary doesn't allow duplicate keys, I couldn't get this result.

I don't need any [ , ] brackets, and extra {, } braces ,  I need exactly the same format that mentioned above.   I tried with json.dumps(..) method.

Comment: Can you tell us more about why you need such duplicated keys?

Comment: note that many implementations of the JSON spec also don't allow for duplicated keys

Comment: From [RFC 7159, page 6](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#page-6): *The names within an object SHOULD be unique.* The specification is explicit that JSON implementations are not required to be to interpret documents where objects have entries with non-unique names in any particular way. (I'm surprised that this is a SHOULD and not a MUST, which would make the document format you're asking for explicitly noncompliant).

Comment: Looks like you need to use an array

Answer (score 3):

You can't; that's a contradiction in terms.  A Python `dict`, by definition, does not have duplicate keys.  It appears to me that you might want to promote everything one level, so that you dict looks like:

```
{
"Employees": {
    "john": {
         ....
    },
    "Taylor": {
         ....   
    },
    "Prab": {
         ....
    }
}
```